# While parsing an Excel file, how do I create variables using the column names in the same Excel file?

Tags: javascript

I have an Excel file which looks like below:

[image]

While parsing the file, instead of creating variables manually, I want to use the column names to be used automatically. Is it possible?

For each row, it should loop in something like this:

```js
Name = "John";
Age = "29";
Country = "USA";
```

I have a bigger file to parse which has more than 100 columns.

Comment: Why? How are you planning on using those variables? I don't think the dupe target is appropriate, this looks more like an XY problem.

Comment: How are you currently parsing the Excel file? Without knowing what you have it's impossible to suggest something...

Comment: The bigger file I am working on. For now I am using something like this (if that helps).

var headers = parser.getColumnHeaders();
gs.info(headers);
var headerCount = headers.length;
var header1 = header[0];
var header2 = header[1];
var header3 = header[2];

Comment: I thought of using like following. But it will be confusing while referring variables from the big file.

var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; ++i) {
    markers[i] = "some stuff";
}